# Can express-session be used in React Native?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, express, cookies

My React Native app needs to use sessions for when users are signed in, but I'm not sure how to implement it. At first I thought I'd need AsyncStorage to store the session ID and attach it to each request to the server, but now I'm wondering if any additional code is required on the client side.

For example, I believe `express-session` sets a cookie automatically in the browser which means you just have to send the cookie. Is this the same for React Native/mobile applications? In other words, if I send a response that contains a cookie will that cookie automatically be attached to each future request, or do I need to store it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) ?, it automatically set the cookie it receive to client when you specify the option `withCredentials: true`.
example:

```js
axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/api/auth/login',
            data: {
                username: username,
                hashpass: hash(password) 
            },
            withCredentials: true
        }).then(res => console.log('login success'))
            .catch(res => {
                   console.log('error')
            })
```

Comment: I know it does this on the browser, but doesn't it fail on mobile? I read that iOS and Android set cookies differently, so I'm not sure if Axios will automatically set the cookie or not.